# How to find the gradient of $f(x) = \frac{\exp(x)}{1^T\exp(x)}$, where $x$ is a vector, $1$ is all-one vector, and $\exp(x)$ is componentwise?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, jacobian

How to find the gradient of
$$f(x) = \frac{\exp(x)}{1^T\exp(x)},$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector, $1$ is all-one vector, and $\exp(x)$ is componentwise?

---

I think I do not compute it correctly since gradient should be matrix.

my attempt:

Let $\alpha(x) = 1^T\exp(x)$ such that
\begin{align}
f(x) 
&= \frac{\exp(x)}{1^T\exp(x)} = \alpha(x)^{-1} \exp(x) \\
\end{align}

I started with a differential but then got confused how to proceed as I get something strange...
\begin{align}
df(x) 
&= d\alpha(x)^{-1} \exp(x) + \alpha(x)^{-1} \ d\exp(x)\\
&\stackrel{??}{=} -\alpha(x)^{-2} \exp(x) dx \exp(x) + \alpha(x)^{-1} \exp(x) dx
\end{align}

Any suggestion how to proceed?

Comment: Gradient? Of a vector field?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo A better terminology may be Jacobian. But I think most of the people call it still gradient if I am not wrong

Comment: I have never met such people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the variables
$$\eqalign{
e &= \exp(x), \qquad
&E = {\rm Diag}(e), \qquad
&de = e\odot dx &= E\,dx \\
\alpha &={\tt1}^Te,\qquad&&d\alpha={\tt1}^TE\,dx &= e^Tdx \\
}$$
where $\odot$ denotes the componentwise/Hadamard product, which is necessary when differentiating componentwise functions. It is often eliminated in favor of diagonal matrices.

Write the function using these variables.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \alpha^{-1}e,\quad\quad F = {\rm Diag}(f) \\
}$$
Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
df
 &= \alpha^{-1}de + e\,d\alpha^{-1} \\
 &= \alpha^{-1}de - e\,\alpha^{-2}d\alpha \\
 &= \alpha^{-1}E\,dx - \alpha^{-2}e(e^Tdx) \\
 &= \left(F - ff^T\right)dx \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
 &= F - ff^T \\
}$$

Answer (score 1):

Denote this components of $f$ as $f_i$, i.e.,

$$f(x) = \begin{pmatrix} f_1(x)\\\vdots\\ f_n(x)\end{pmatrix}$$

Take the derivative of each component w.r.t. each input,

$$\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} = \partial_{x_j} (\exp(x_i)/1^T\exp(x))$$

Break it into two cases: $i=j$ and $i\neq j$.

$i=j$ case:

$$\partial_{x_i}\left(\frac{\exp(x_i)}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\exp(x_k)}\right) = \frac{\exp(x_i)}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\exp(x_k)}\left(1 - \frac{\exp(x_i)}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\exp(x_k)}\right)=f_i(1-f_i)$$

$i\neq j$ case:

$$\partial_{x_j}\left(\frac{\exp(x_i)}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\exp(x_k)}\right) =\left(\frac{-\exp(x_j)\exp(x_i)}{\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \exp(x_k)\right)^2}\right)=-f_jf_i$$

Comment: Thank you TSF (+1 from my side)